# Check if a document exists

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to check if a document exists in my collection "users" because when I try this code, it seems not to enter in the `OnCompleteListener` when the document doesn't exist (when no documents have a correct value with the field "user_uid") :

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("user_uid", user.getUid())
        .limit(1).get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                } else {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

When I have a document with my condition `whereEqualTo("user_uid", user.getUid())`, it's working.

So, how can I check if there is a document where the field `"user_uid" == user.getUid()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your code, and tried your implementation of `OnCompleteListener` with `limit(1)`. It worked with me on both scenarios where there are results, and no results.

`Firestore` has a way to check if there is no results by checking if it [`isEmpty()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot.html#isEmpty()) or not, before performing any operations. Because performing any operation will cause `IndexOutOfBoundsException` most of the time with iterating on `getDocuments()`.

for example:

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    boolean isEmpty = task.getResult().isEmpty();
}
```

I hope this will help you.